# split string contain html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, split, cpu-word

i have this html string:

```
this simple the<b>html string</b> text test that<b>need</b>to<b>spl</b>it it too
```

i want to split it and have result array like this :

```
this simple 
the<b>html string<b>
text test 
that<b>need</b>to<b>spl</b>it
it too
```

i tried  this  way :

```
     var string ='this simple the<b>html string</b> text test that<b>need</b>to<b>spl</b>it it too';
     var regex =  XRegExp('((?:[\\p{L}\\p{Mn}]+|)<\\s*.*?[^>]*>.*?<\/.*?>(?:[\\p{L}\\p{Mn}]+|))', "g");
 
    result = string.split(regex);
```

it didn't work i don't want split word by word is there way to do it ...

Comment: You try to to split it at what condition?!

Comment: yes i want to match whole words that contain multi tag or one tag and split the string as shown in in array i provide

Comment: That makes no sense, you have word `the` in two "object arrays" that have no tags around it. And `it`

Comment: `string.split(/(?:^|\s+)([^\s<>]+(?:\s+[^\s<>]+)*)(?:\s+|$)/).filter(Boolean)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HUW1ia/2))

Comment: `string.split(/((?<=\s)\w+<\w>.*?<\/\w>.*?(?=\s))/);` - You can also try this.

Comment: ok thank you will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
string.split(/\s*(?<!\S)([^\s<>]+(?:\s+[^\s<>]+)*)(?!\S)\s*/).filter(Boolean);
```

Capturing group will enable saving the matches as part of the resulting array.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s<>]+                 any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '<', '>' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s<>]+                 any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '<', '>' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

JavaScript:

```js
const string = 'this simple the<b>html string</b> text test that<b>need</b>to<b>spl</b>it it too';
const regex= /\s*(?<!\S)([^\s<>]+(?:\s+[^\s<>]+)*)(?!\S)\s*/;
console.log(string.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

Output:

```
[
  "this simple",
  "the<b>html string</b>",
  "text test",
  "that<b>need</b>to<b>spl</b>it",
  "it too"
]
```

Comment: what if tag contain values or attributes like :"the<b style ='color:red'>html string</b>",

Comment: and also what if string had only this string : 

"the<b class ='test test2>html string</b>"

 i want also to get it in regx

Comment: @جومارتميرزا Try `string.split(/\s*((?:[^\s<]*<\w[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\w[^>]*>)+[^\s<]*)\s*/)`

Comment: thank you again for you concern this really what i want  it really solved big issues with me thanks again

Comment: i need help plz what if the match contain new line like this 
https://regex101.com/r/20zEyO/3

Comment: Looks fine to me.